# Weird error when running phpUnit test suite from Zend Studio 8

Tags: php, phpunit, pear, zend-studio

Zend Studio 8 has phpUnit integration and a dedicated view, which is great, so I would like to use it... but:

When I run my phpunit.xml on the command line, the tests are executed just fine, when I try to run phpunit.xml in Zend Studio as unit test, I get the following fatal error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'PHPUnit_Framework_Error' with message
>   'Assigning the return value of new by
>   reference is deprecated' in C:\Program
>   Files
>   (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\bin\PEAR\PEAR\Config.php:650

Stack trace:

> #0 C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\bin\PEAR\PEAR\RunTest.php(22):
>   ZendPHPUnitErrorHandler->handle(8192,
>   'Assigning the r...', 'C:\Program
>   File...', 650, Array)
>    #1 C:\Program
>   Files
>   (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\bin\PEAR\PEAR\RunTest.php(22):
>   require_once()
>    #2 C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\bin\PEAR\PHPUnit\Extensions\PhptTestCase.php(49):
>   require_once('C:\Program File...')
>    #3
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Zend
>   Studio -
>   8.0.0\plugins\com.zend.php.phpunit_8.0.0.v20101001-0100\resources\ZendPHPUnit.php(103):
>   require_once('C:\Program File...')
>    #4
>   {main} thrown in C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\bin\PEAR\PEAR\Config.php
>   on line 650

I really don't have a clue what that means... why should some deprecated code in the PEAR config keep my tests from running?

[edit]
**Some additional information**:

My colleague who has neither PEAR nor phpunit installed, can run unit tests from Zend Studio 8 just fine but he can't run any from the CLI. So it seems that Zend Studio not only integrates with phpUnit but comes bundled with a version of it. I wanted the newest version and that's why I installed PEAR and then via PEAR I installed phpUnit. As a consequence, the phpUnit library of Zend Studio was outdated and I had to replace the file 'ZendPHPUnit.php' in the Zend Studio plugin folder with a version of a Zend Forum user. This lead to correct inclusion of the phpUnit classes and the current problem.
[/edit]

Comment: Did you update all your pear packages already?

Comment: You might also want to ask this on the Zend Forum: http://forums.zend.com and try http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=59&t=10468

Comment: Thanks for all the hints so far! pear upgrade and pear upgrade-all results in 'nothing to upgrade' so I guess I'm fine there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Line 650 in PEAR\Config.php does

```
$this->_registry['default'] = &new PEAR_Registry(
    $this->configuration['default']['php_dir']
);
```

This will raise an [`E_DEPRECATED`](http://php.net/manual/en/migration53.deprecated.php) message depending on whether you have enabled error_reporting to include that level. The error handlers of `PHPUnit` and `ZendPHPUnit` will convert those to `PHPUnit_Framework_Exceptions`.

Because PHP will raise `E_DEPRECATED` already at compile time, the only way to suppress these errors is in php.ini. My assumption is, that your PHPUnit you run from CLI is using a different php.ini than that your Zend Studio and in that php.ini the error level is not low enough to raise `E_DEPRECATED`.

If you can provide a reproducable example, we might be able to make more sense of it. In any case, try to update your PEAR installation to the latest version.

Comment: Thanks! I am also using Zend Server CE and the error level is set to E_ALL & E_STRICT. So this shouldn't create any problems. I am now trying to find out, what the CLI uses but have now clue why it should use another php.ini and where that should be located.

Comment: @markus run `php -i | more` to get the phpinfo() of your CLI. There should be a line "Configuration File (php.ini) Path" and "Loaded Configuration File" at the first few lines pointing to the location of the file.

Comment: @Gordon: The loaded configuration file is the one of my Zend Server CE, maybe it's rather the case that Zend Studio uses a different one when running phpUnit... but I cannot find any other php.ini files on my system.

Comment: @markus running phpinfo() from a script within Zend Studio should tell you which ini they are using. You are right btw that Zend Studio uses it' own (outdated) version of PHPUnit. In any case, try with the Zend Forums or - even better - open a ticket with Zend Support (as I have no clue how to fix it)

Comment: @Gordon: I'll find a solution, thanks for your help! I don't like the Zend Forums, I have three old open and unanswered questions there already... and I'm not eligible for Zend Support yet, since I'm in my 60 days trial... which would actually mean Zend should want to answer my questions, if they want to sell their product... Zend Studio is great but it sucks.